# have stackpanel clickable and load viewport

Tags: c#, onclick, uwp, viewport, stackpanel

first post here so if I do anything wrong please slap me.

I'm currently trying to learn UWP code and I want to try to create a bottom naivation bar. I'm trying to work with stackpanels to do so

The idea is that when a stackpanel is clicked / tapped it should load a new page into viewport, however I can't figure out the correct code to do so. Here's an short version of my stackpanel:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
        <StackPanel Name="FirstButton" Tapped="FirstButton_Tapped">
            <TextBlock x:Name="Icon1" />
            <TextBlock x:Name="Text1" />
        </StackPanel>
         <StackPanel Name="SecondButton" Tapped="SecondButton_Tapped">
            <TextBlock x:Name="Icon2" />
            <TextBlock x:Name="Text2" />
        </StackPanel>
         <StackPanel Name="ThirdButton" Tapped="ThirdButton_Tapped">
            <TextBlock x:Name="Icon3" />
            <TextBlock x:Name="Text3" />
        </StackPanel>
```

I chose stackpanel because that was the best way for me to  have a bottom and horizontal aligned bar with an icon on top and text displaying under it.
(if you got a better idea feel free to post it)

Now the question is how i should write my C# code so that the Tapped event will load a second page into the viewport.

(further, the style I'm aiming for is something similar to what deezer uses, example is here: http://imgur.com/WNNi96v

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Pedro G. Dias says far better to use `Button` control as it has many more benefits (Visual States) that you associate with user clicking/ Tapping a Button rather than using the `Tap` event of `StackPanel`

You can customise a `Button` easily by utilising the `ContentTemplate`

```
 <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
        <Button x:Name="FirstButton" Click="FirstButton_Click">
            <Button.ContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="Icon1" />
                        <TextBlock x:Name="Text1" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Button.ContentTemplate>
        </Button>
        <!--More buttons here-->
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Thank you both SWilko and Pedro, it worked out great and thank you so much for your time! much love <3

Answer (score 0):

Simply create buttons and place them inside each stackpanel. The button.Content property of the Button control will let you put the two textblocks inside it.

Comment: Thank you both SWilko and Pedro, it worked out great and thank you so much for your time! much love <3

Comment: No problem. Dont forget to tag the answer so that the question is closed